# Unresolved static symbols in constructor while using another class's static member function.

Tags: c++, class, constructor, static-members

I have two classes, `Foo` and `Bar`.

Foo.h

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static void Setm(int i) { m = i; }
private:
    static int m;
};
```

Bar.h

```
class Foo;
class Bar
{
 public:
     Bar(int m) {Foo::Setm(m);}
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"
void main() {
   Bar bar(5);
}
```

When I compile I get these errors:
1>Foo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int Foo::m" (?m@Foo@@0HA)
1>Bar.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int Foo::m" (?m@Fool@@0HA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things.

- You should include header guards:

Example:

```
//Foo.H
#ifndef __FOO_H__
#define __FOO_H__
...
...
#endif
```

- Bar.H should be including Foo.H if its implementing a constructor that requires knowledge of Foo's implementation. (**You are**)

  - This is another problem you will likely run into later.
- The static member does **NOT** have to be initialized in global scope, it has to be defined once and only once.

  - See below for further explanation.  This answer is abbreviated from http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/link-errs-static-data-mems.html where your exact problem is roughly described. and see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-const-with-initializers.html for slightly more information.

Despite what the other answers state, main is a horrible place to do this.  Doing so requires everyone who ever uses this class to have know to do this in their main.  How the heck would I know to define static constants in my main when I want to use your header (or even another developer on your team or for another block of code) ? The answer is I wouldn't.  It's a lazy practice that will form a bad habit. And don't even get me started on static initialization/destruction fun.

You can't put it in Foo.H because doing so would result in linker errors from the redefinition by every compilation unit that includes your header.

A far better place to do this is in a newly created Foo.[c|.cxx|.cpp|.cc] (whatever suffix you use). 
Does main work? Yes it works... for you right now. Will it cause issues later? Probably. Is it good form and a solution to be remembered?  Absolutely not.

**Best Answer**:

```
//Foo.C (NOT MAIN)  
#include<Foo.h>  
int Foo::m = 0;
```

What you should also notice is nothing about my answer has anything do with a second class using it in its constructor.  Were I to have the points, I would edit the title of your question because it has nothing to do with constructors or class member functions. You are talking about static class methods/functions  not member functions/methods.

Answer (score 2):

A static class member variable for any non integral/enum type must be initialized outside of its declaration/definition.

One such place can be the global scope from main.

i.e. in main.cpp:

```
 int Foo::m = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
int FOO::m = 0;
```

Outside the class definition in a implementation file.

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize static variable:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static int m;
static void Setm(int i) { m = i; }
private:
};
int Foo::m=2;

class Foo;
class Bar
{
 public:
 Bar(int m) {Foo::Setm(m);}
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Foo::Setm(5);
    Bar b(5);
    return 0;
}
```